# Set Custom Coordinates to a function, Waze Integration

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, coordinates, waze

I'm trying to implement navigation using `Waze` in my App, using their own API: [here](https://www.waze.com/about/dev).

I want to set in `custom coordinates` that are set in an `array`
and then fit them in this **code:**

```
func navigate(toLatitude latitude: Double , longitude: Double) {
                if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string: "waze://")!) {
                    // Waze is installed. Launch Waze and start navigation
                    let urlStr: String = "waze://?ll=\(latitude),\(longitude)&navigate=yes"
                    UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: urlStr)!)
                }
                else {
                    // Waze is not installed. Launch AppStore to install Waze app
                    UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: "http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id323229106")!)
                }
            }
```

i have tried settings up different type of arrays but didn't succeed to make it work . So if you could help me out set custom array holding latitude and longitude that would work properly with the code, that would be awesome

your help will be very much helpful,

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by custom coordinates?

Comment: Like i would create my own array of coordinates that i control their degrees and i would set the func to navigate to that array of coordinates. you understand now? @Subramanian

Comment: But their apis are not supporting array of coordinates right..

Comment: So how do i control where to navigate? @Subramanian

Comment: `waze://?ll=<lat>,<lon>&navigate=yes`, only has destination `lat lon` values. I think it will navigate to destination from your current location

Comment: But i can control the lat and long right?

Comment: Yes, you can pass `Destination lat long ` as a parameter.

Comment: How can i do that?

Comment: Your question itself has that function...

Comment: `let urlStr: String = "waze://?ll=\(latitude),\(longitude)&navigate=yes"` this line of code will open the app with your `Lat Lon` values

Comment: so i want to change those lat and log to degrees i want to.. is it possible? @Subramanian

Comment: do you mean CLLocationCordinates or CLLocationDegrees?

Comment: i think CLLocationDegrees since i want to control the longitude and latitude

Comment: I will add a answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Waze` app supporting only destination `latitude` and `longitude`.

`waze://?ll=<lat>,<lon>&navigate=yes`

`CLLocationCordiates` will expect two parameters `latitude` and `longitude`, which is `CLLocationDegrees` type. `CLLocationDegrees` is nothing but `Double` value.

```
let location =  CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
```

If you have double values then no need to construct as `CLLocationCoordinate2D`. You can use the same `function` -> `navigate()` which you mentioned in your question

Pass the value to a below function to open `Waze` app.

```
func openWaze(location : CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string: "waze://")!) {
        // Waze is installed. Launch Waze and start navigation
        let urlStr: String = "waze://?ll=\(location.latitude),\(location.longitude)&navigate=yes"
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: urlStr)!)
    }
    else {
        // Waze is not installed. Launch AppStore to install Waze app
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: "http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id323229106")!)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey for some reason the action is not being called.... which is weird  ... check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44999453/alertviewcontroller-button-function-not-working

Comment: Thanks! with your help and other i got this thing working properly....Thank a lot man :)

Answer (score 5):

When compiling with iOS SDK 9.0 and later, you must update your application's property list file with the following to include Waze:

```html
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
  <string>waze</string>
</array>
```

Answer (score 0):

To Create custom array for holding lat and long :

```
NSMutableArray *latLongArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[latLongArray addObject :[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:lat,@"latitude",long,@"longitude",nil]];
[latLongArray addObject :[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:lat,@"latitude",long,@"longitude",nil]];
[latLongArray addObject :[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:lat,@"latitude",long,@"longitude",nil]];
```

Substitute lat long values.