# UIAlertController button function not working

Tags: ios, swift, function, uialertcontroller

```
let location =  CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 32.075300, longitude: 34.782563)

    @IBAction func DirectionsTolocationButton(_ sender: Any) {
        // Create the AlertController and add its actions like button in ActionSheet
        let ActionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "Please Select A Navigation Service.", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

        let AppleMapsButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Apple Maps", style: .default) { action -> Void in

            let destinationName = (self.barNameTemplate ) 
            self.openMapsAppWithDirections(to: self.CoordinatesTemplate, destinationName: destinationName)
            print("Apple Map Chosen!")

        }
        let WazeButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Waze", style: .default) { action -> Void in

            func openWaze(location : CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
                if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string: "waze://")!) {
                    // Waze is installed. Launch Waze and start navigation
                    let urlStr: String = "waze://?ll=\(location.latitude),\(location.longitude)&navigate=yes"
                    UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: urlStr)!)
                }
                else {
                    // Waze is not installed. Launch AppStore to install Waze app
                    UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: "http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id323229106")!)
                }
            }
            print("Waze Chosen!")
        }
```

When i choose WazeButton nothing happens... as Waze says in their API iv added this to my Plist as well :

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
        <string>waze</string>
</array>
```

why it doesn't work for me?

Comment: The only code inside the action handler for the Waze button is another function that you make no attempt to call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add function out side the function and call as below.

```
func openWaze(location : CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
                if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string: "waze://")!) {
                    // Waze is installed. Launch Waze and start navigation
                    let urlStr: String = "waze://?ll=\(location.latitude),\(location.longitude)&navigate=yes"
                    UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: urlStr)!)
                }
                else {
                    // Waze is not installed. Launch AppStore to install Waze app
                    UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: "http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id323229106")!)
                }
            }
```

**Calling as below**

```
let WazeButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Waze", style: .default) { action -> Void in

            self. openWaze(location : your corrdinates)// call here your function
            print("Waze Chosen!")
        }
```

Comment: Or simply eliminate the function.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! This is working perfectly :D , Also thanks for your  explanations @rmaddy i learned a new thing today, thanks guys :)